# How to deal with nested Observable fields?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I do have the following view model objects in my Swift code:

```
class AssetModel {    
  var assetOrder: Observable<Int>
  var title: Observable<String?>
  var thumbnailImageName: Observable<String?>
}

class SectionModel {    
  var assets: Observable<[AssetModel]>
}
```

At the UI level, I am willing to subscribe to the assets variable and execute some custom logic for each asset. That is where I get stuck because the asset object has `Observable` fields and I am not sure how to deal with these nested fields. Here is what I am doing:

```
sectionModel.assets.subscribe(onNext: { assets in 
    assets.forEach { asset in
        asset.assetOrder.subscribe(onNext: { order in }) // another subscribe here looks very odd
    }
})
```

The custom logic I will execute needs the `order`, `title` and `thumbnailImageName` fields at the same time. How do I get all of those 3 fields? I can `flatMap` them separately but also is defeating the purpose of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you shouldn't have observable of observables, so you can edit AssetModel like this:

```
class AssetModel {    
    var assetOrder: Int
    var title: String?
    var thumbnailImageName: String?
}
```

But if it isn't possible, you should combine observables like this:

```
typealias AssetTuple = (assetOrder: Int, title: String?, thumbnailImageName: String?)
sectionModel.assets
    .flatMapLatest { asset -> Observable<AssetTuple> in
        let observables = asset.map {
            Observable.combineLatest(
                $0.assetOrder,
                $0.title,
                $0.thumbnailImageName
            ) { AssetTuple($0, $1, $2) }
        }
        return Observable.merge(observables)
    }
```

or

```
typealias AssetTuple = (assetOrder: Int, title: String?, thumbnailImageName: String?)
sectionModel.assets
    .flatMapLatest { asset -> Observable<[AssetTuple]> in
        let observables = asset.map {
            Observable.combineLatest(
                $0.assetOrder,
                $0.title,
                $0.thumbnailImageName
            ) { AssetTuple($0, $1, $2) }
        }
        return Observable.combineLatest(observables)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This is also what I had in mind, great to see that somebody else has the same idea. It looks pretty ugly and you are probably right, I shouldn't have an observable of observables in the first place. Let me check the data model if that can be changed.